# Jquery Accordion With Table inside

Tags: jquery, height, accordion

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
<div id="accordion">
<% i = 0 %>
        @handle_paises.each do |pais|          
            @handle_publi_pais = Paquete.paque_pais(pais.id_pais)
            if !@handle_publi_pais.blank? %>
              <h3><a href="#"><%= pais.nombre %></a></h3>
              <div class="section">
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="paque_tr_5">
                  <%@handle_publi_pais.each do |pais_cargado|%>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="71%" align="left" valign="top" id="paque_tr_1">
                          <%= pais_cargado.nombre_promocion.to_s %>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center" valign="bottom" id="paque_tr_3">
                          <a href="xxx" title="yyy">
                            <img src="yyy"  width="26" height="18" border="0"/>
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <% i += 1 end%>
                </table>
              </div>
            <% end%>
</div>
```

however, each section is rendered with a HUGE height (which is added I don't know how to the  (and no, this class doesn't have any entry on any css file)

Why is this happening?

Thanxxx

UPDATE:

this is the output of the

```
<div class="section ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 663.6px;" role="tabpanel">
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/GaqLZ/2/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or post the output rather than the html with the inline code?  Your javascript may help also.

Comment: I only have this in my .js file:
$("#accordion").accordion();

Comment: Like @kingjiv said, a jsfiddle would help us the most with the actual rendered output (and not the ruby bits).  It looks to me like you have potentially broken rendering code?  lots of ruby code in this view but doesn't seem to have the appropriate number of `<%` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the autoHeight option:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({autoHeight: false, collapsible: true});    
});
```

`autoHeight` defaults to true and makes all of the div's the same size.  So it looks for the one that is the tallest, and uses that height for every single one.  `autoHeight: false` makes each individual div only as tall as it's content.

You can add the `collapsible: true` property if you want the individual nodes to be close-able after opening them.

Answer (score 2):

heightStyle: "fill" is the property you're looking for.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true, heightStyle: "fill" });
```